# Strange shape for colored background in chat app

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make some small chat app, with a grey background around the message:

[image]

The problem is that the grey background is a strange shape (like what I drew in red) rather than a simple rounded rectangle:

```
messageLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width-94, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude+32)
messageLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
messageLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0
messageLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neuse", size: 17)
messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
messageLbl.text = self.messageArray[i]
messageLbl.sizeToFit()
messageLbl.layer.zPosition = 20
//messageLbl.frame.origin.x = (self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width - self.messageX) - messageLbl.frame.size.width //--> value of 449.5 too much right
messageLbl.frame.origin.y = self.messageY
//messageLbl.frame.origin.y = 20
messageLbl.frame.origin.x = 40
self.resultsScrollView.addSubview(messageLbl)
self.messageY += messageLbl.frame.size.height + 30
let frameLbl:UILabel = UILabel()
frameLbl.frame.size = CGSize(width: messageLbl.frame.size.width, height: messageLbl.frame.size.height + 10)
//frameLbl.frame.origin.x = (self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width - self.frameX) - frameLbl.frame.size.width
frameLbl.frame.origin.x = 20
frameLbl.frame.origin.y = self.frameY
frameLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
frameLbl.layer.masksToBounds = true
frameLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.resultsScrollView.addSubview(frameLbl)
self.frameY += frameLbl.frame.size.height + 20
let img: UIImageView = UIImageView()
img.image = self.myImg
img.frame.size = CGSize(width: 34,height: 34)
//img.frame.origin.x = (self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width - self.imgX) - img.frame.size.width
frameLbl.frame.origin.x = 70
img.frame.origin.y = self.imgY

img.layer.zPosition = 30
img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.size.width/2
img.clipsToBounds = true
self.resultsScrollView.addSubview(img)
self.imgY += frameLbl.frame.height + 20
self.resultsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: theWidth, height: self.messageY)
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController or read it https://robkerr.com/tutorial-creating-an-ios-chat-bubble-with-tails-in-swift-the-easy-way-9f4db2c26aa

Comment: @GIJOW I will take a look thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frameLbl.frame.origin.x = 70
```

This code is weird. You can move the x to 40 and see the result.